# Filtering DTO in by role or granular permission

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Is there a way to filter a DTO based on permissions?

As an example:

```
class User {
    int id {get; set}
    string secretInfo {get; set}
    string publicInfo {get; set}
}
```

If a client is requesting data, only remove secretInfo without creating a new object? It becomes a real pain to create and manage those for every permission.

If I have and Admin and Non-Admin user, I must create a new DTO for every permission? Or is there a way with attributes or something like that which can filter data? Or is it a bad practice?

Comment: You can create a view model. Mimic all the properties minus the secretInfo string

Comment: Yes I tought of that, but how can I return in the same call two different viewmodels? If the user is A -> ViewModelSimplified / If the user is B ViewModelComplete

Comment: have you tried to return as interface :)

Comment: As I see all properties in an interface are required. Can you give an example? As I see will not be able to return secretInfo with an interface that has only publicInfo

Answer (score 1):

I can see three different ways to solve this:

An inherited interface, and then cast it to the chosen interface (public or private):

```
interface IPublicUser {
    int id {get; set;}
    string publicInfo {get; set;}
}

interface ISecretUser : IPublicUser {
    string secretInfo {get; set;}
}
class User : ISecretUser {
    int id {get; set;}
    string secretInfo {get; set;}
    string publicInfo {get; set;}
}
```

Managing the data inside the properties

```
class User : ISecretUser {
    int id {get; set;}
    bool accessGranted {get; set;}
    string secretInfo {
      get {
            if (accessGranted)
              return _secretInfo;
            else
              return null;
          }
      set {
            if (accessGranted)
              _secretInfo = value;
          }
    }
    string _secretInfo;
    string publicInfo {get; set;}
}
```

The third way is using two different ViewModels where you can manage what to show to the user...

Comment: ISecretUser : IPublicUser :D

Comment: Seems so overly complicated.... What about having attributes [Public] [Private] and a function that clears all private marked values before sending